# Android ListFragment Runtime Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment that is crashing when its called. I do not know how to fix this. I would appreciate a new pair of eyes. So lets get into it, here is my code and error log.

**Fragment**

```
public class Incidents_Frag extends ListFragment {
View view;
public static Model model;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.incid, container, false);
    model = new Model();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Incident>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, model.getIncidents()));        
    return view;
}
}
```

**Fragment XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890): java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:809)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:417)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-21 23:54:30.615: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As we can see from the error log I am apparently trying to inflate something that is not of the type "listview". I actually added the listview inside the fragment xml aftewards with an id of "list" just to see if it would work. It didn't. I think the key is in the 2nd line of the error log yet I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you for any help offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're creating a new "list" id, but you should be using the one provided by android: `android:id="@id/android:list"`

Comment: that worked. Now its not displaying my array im passing, but thats a seperate question